# WPF - Load Control and Resources at design time

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've an assembly which contains many xaml files of resource dictionaries.

Then, I've many assemblies which contains wpf custom controls (*.cs files).

All my resource dictionaries and all my Wpf custom controls are coupled at Runtime and all works perfectly.
Also, by this way, I'm able to switch all templates at design time by loading a different assembly of themes via reflection.

The issue: actually, I'm not able to see any custom control at design time.

The simplest case is the following:
I've a custom control (*.cs file only) which inherit from Button class. Then, I override OnApplyTemplate method in order to load my resources that are loaded at Runtime from the other assembly, so the visual studio designer is unable to render my custom control.

Is there some workaround in order to see my controls at design time?

Comment: There may be some exception at design time making your controls unable to be shown. So you should be able to detect when it's in design mode to handle code accordingly. Of course if the resource loadable only at runtime determines some part of your control's appearance, then it cannot look right at design time. But at least you should see it as a place holder (and native enough). To detect design mode in WPF, try using the `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode` method.

Comment: No, it's impossibile because my custom control overrides OnApplyTemplate in order to search the resource that are loaded at Runtime (from the other assembly via reflection), so visual studio is unable to render any control at design time. I would to know if there is some way to avoid this behavior.